# Use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server?

Tags: server, 16.04

**Please excuse me for being ignorant, but I need some advise.**

I have been working in Ubuntu system since past 2 years.

Recently, our group has purchased a server, and I need to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it.

Though I can install it, I have few queries that I would like to get addressed.

1. Can multiple users access the same package simultaneously? I would be mainly using open source libraries.
2. How to install a package to make it accessible to all users?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. The usual methods: `sudo apt-get install`, use Ubuntu Software, etc.

Comment: Thankyou, I was looking for this much needed assurance from the experienced users to avoid glitches in future.

Comment: @muru So from a user point of view, there is no difference in Ubuntu-Desktop and Ubuntu-Server, rather latter comes with the added advantage of multiple user accessibility feature.

Please confirm this.

Comment: from a user POV, Ubuntu Desktop is Ubuntu Server + desktop packages installed.

Comment: Do you mean to say that Ubuntu-Desktop eliminate the use of Ubuntu-Server. If Ubuntu-Desktop is Ubuntu-Server + desktop packages, then can I go with Ubuntu-Desktop instead of Ubuntu-Server. What would you recommend based on my above-mentioned queries?

Comment: do you need a GUI? If not, there's no point to installing the desktop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41384/discussion-between-mario-and-muru).

Answer (score 2):

By default, most installed packages will be available to all users.  Some adminstrative tools and utilities may be restricted to the root user, but generally, all applications, packages, libraries, and binaries will be available system-wide.

To install a package, use `apt install packagename`.

Comment: I would be mainly installing MATLAB, Climatic Data Operato, qGIS,r and some widely use Modeling libraries. Hope these will be excluded from restriction.

Thanks for the much needed confirmation.

Comment: In the case of commercial packages such as Matlab, whether it is available to multiple users (and exactly how - for example, whether it allows multiple *concurrent* users) may be determined by the terms of your licence.